# How are Boneless Wings Made

Tags: chicken-wings

How are the bones taken out of chicken wings to get boneless wings? Is the meat in boneless wings even from chicken wings or a different part of the  chicken?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well; boneless wings cover a wide breadth of different styles; so no one size fits all answer.

1. Breaded breast meat or chicken tenderloin breaded; probably the higher end version.
2. The hotdog of chicken; chopped up leftovers formed into shape and breaded.  Basically a big chicken nugget with more texture to meat.
3. Plethora of a mixture of above

Ironically they usually don't contain any chicken wing meat.

Answer (score 2):

They're generally just breast meat, if they're nice ones as opposed to glorified chicken nuggets. If you [google "boneless chicken wings"](https://www.google.com/search?q=boneless%20chicken%20wings) you'll find plenty of results corroborating this.

[This recipe](http://allrecipes.com/recipe/151266/boneless-buffalo-wings/) calls for "3 skinless, boneless chicken breasts, cut into 1/2-inch strips". [This one](http://blogchef.net/how-to-make-boneless-chicken-wings/) calls for "3 boneless skinless chicken breasts (cut into 1” chunks)". [WingStop's menu](http://www.wingstop.com/menu/ways/boneless/) says "Our boneless wings are 100% all-white breast meat...".